# C# Automatically login to website on special port

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, autologin

I use a website alot, so I'm creating a tool that would assist me in using it and retrieving data from it at ease. The website I deal with is built using JSP.

The tool I'm building will be done using WPF under C#. So what I need to do (and don't know how to) is connect to the website (HttpWebRequest or something similar), login (username and password along with some other parameters are sent via POST method) as well as request header information like referer and so on ...

I would like someone to guide me on how to create an application that would connect to the website, log in and then navigate to two or three different pages and then retrieve a file or just copy the HTML code and I will deal with the rest.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You have to break it down into specific questions - e.g. how to automate the login.

Comment: Login is usually håndled by sending some value in the http requests 'Authorization' header. The exact value depends on the authorization model, but it will be either a username/password encoding (in basic auth) or some kind of session token obtained by providing uid/pwd to a login page. Tokens may also be stored in cookies. Your question cannot be answered without knowing these details. If you don't know these details you may have to sniff the traffic.

Comment: @faester : I have all the details I need like the header details and the post details. But I can't publish them as this is an internal website with classified info.

Comment: @sikas: all modern cryptography is based on public algorithms and secret keys. It should be safe to tell which authentication mechanisms are in use as long as you don't reveal the pwds. And helping you without such info is hard :)

Comment: @faester: I'm not the owner of the website, but I did use tamper data on FF in order to get all the post data and see in what format it is sent. So all I'm seeking is the method of connecting and sending the data via POST as well as setting HEADER information. I can store all required data in Array and load the array values and proceed with what I need to do ... I just need the steps and a sample code to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you basically answered your own questions. Use the web connect library in C#, login and pull the HTML text using GetResponse().

Comment: Can you provide an example about that? and how to load next URL with referring to the previously opened one.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From our small discussion in the comments to your question I interpret your question as more related to how to set authentication and http verb when doing web requests from within .NET, than a question related to security. Sorry if I misunderstand you.

You mention the `HttpWebRequest` which is also where I would start.

You create the instance with the static `Create` method on the `WebRequest`:

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create('https://some.url');
```

You then assign headers using either

```
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = 'your auth token';
```

Some values (like the Date header) cannot be set using the above method, since it has a dedicated property. See the [HttpWebRequest description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) at msdn.

To change the verb/method you can simply use the `Method` string property.

Writing the request and reading the response body is done using the `GetRequestBody` and 'GetResponseBody`methods. They return respectively a write-only/read-only`Stream`. These also exist in async style variants which are preferred if you are doing multi page loads.

Comment: thank you faester, I'll try this and come back 2 u ... and for sure I'll accept your answer once I test :)